# -webkit-column-count reads div from top down instead of left to right

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I am trying to make a fluid grid layout with different heights for the grid and make them flow one after another which is like masonry but I wanna use pure css. A way to do it that I have searched for is from http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/
Sample source code:

```
#myContent {
    -moz-column-count: 6;
    -moz-column-gap: 0px;
    -webkit-column-count: 6;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    column-count: 6;
    column-gap: 0px;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

However, it seems like the data is being displayed from top to bottom for per row than left to right. See their demo for more info. http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/masonry/demos/css.html

Does anyone know how i can make the data render from left to right first.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think you will be unable to use pure css to accomplish this. By definition, columns go from top to bottom and css does not include this functionality for rows as far as I know. Trying to use columns from left to right is just not how the world works.